# MailKit/MimeKit giving error when on PowerShell 4 but works on PowerShell 5.1

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am getting the error, "Argument types do not match" when trying to send email using MailKit/MimeKit versions 2.5.1 when I am on the production server which is using PowerShell 4.0 but works on the developer machine using PowerShell 5.1

The system information for production and developer machines follow:
[image]

I get the error on production in the try/catch after it tries to run $MkSmtp.Send($Message):

[image]

The code I have looks as follows:

```
    #Load the .NET Core class dll for Mailkit based on .NET 4.5
    add-type -path "c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\EmailUtilities\MailKit.dll"
    add-type -path "c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\EmailUtilities\MimeKit.dll"

    #Server and Mailbox properties for less secure access when connecting to google
    $MkSmtp = New-Object MailKit.Net.smtp.SmtpClient
    $CanToken = New-Object System.Threading.CancellationToken ($false)
    $SSL = [MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions]::SslOnConnect
    $MkSmtp.Connect($MailServer, $Port, $SSL, $CanToken)
    $MkSmtp.Authenticate(([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8), $Username, $Password, $CanToken)
    #have the building of the message in a separate function which also worked
    #on development PowerShell 5.1 but not on production PowerShell 4 but rebuilt message
    #here until I figure it out
    #--------------
    $Message = New-Object MimeKit.MimeMessage
    $Message.From.Add($global:EmailFrom)
    $Message.To.Add($global:EmailTo)
    $Message.Subject = "Test";
    $TextPart = New-Object MimeKit.TextPart ("plain")
    $TextPart.Text = "Testing message..."
    $Message.Body = $TextPart
    #$Options = New-Object MimeKit.Net.Smtp.FormatOptions.Default.Clone
    #$Options.International = $true

    #$Message = New-MimeMessage $global:EmailFrom $global:EmailTo $Subject $LogMsg
    $MkSmtp.Send($Message)
    $MkSmtp.Disconnect($true)
    $MkSmtp.Dispose()
    #--------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated our live server to Windows Management Framework 5.1 (PowerShell) and now works as expected just like my development machine.